# Reading values from JSON objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JS code:

```
var response = loadXMLDoc();
var dataset = response.data;
alert(response);
alert (dataset);
```

"alert(response)" prints this:

```
{"labels":["-inf - 10","10 - 20","20 - 30","30 - 40","40 - 50","50 - 60","60 - 70","70 - 80","80 - 90","90 - 100","100 - 110","110 - 120","120 - 130","130 - 140","140 - 150","150 - 160","160 - +inf"],"data":[3,8,7,3,7,6,6,7,5,4,10,7,4,4,7,2,0],"count":16}
```

while "alert(dataset)" gives "undefined". I have tried to use

```
     var dataset = response["data"];
```

but it did not work as well. I want to get the data array from the JSON object. How can i do that.
Thanks

Comment: You have to parse the JSON into a JavaScript object first. See [how to parse json in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript). Also note that there is no key `data` in the JSON (only `labels` and `count`).

Comment: @Felix KlingThanks.. it worked. data key is there though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing that you got alert to show response, it's a string, not yet an object.

You need to parse it with [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON#Parsing_JSON.C2.A0strings)

```
//load your response
var response = loadXMLDoc(),
    dataset;

//parse response
response = JSON.parse(response);

//assign data to dataset
dataset = response.data;

//Hit F12 to see the console
console.log(response);
console.log(dataset);
```

​
[Here's a sample](http://jsfiddle.net/euAss/)

Comment: Your jsFiddle ID is quite insulting to Europeans.

Comment: @Jill-JênnVie lol, tell that to JSFiddle. It's not my fault XD

Answer (score 1):

Use `var y = JSON.parse(response); alert(y["data"])`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var dataset = eval('(' + responce.data + ')');
```

Comment: `responce.d` maybe you meant `response.data`?